# Instalar dependencia en hosting Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dependencias

Estoy utilizando un hosting donde esta mi proyecto ya en produccion, lo que hago es realizar mejoras pero esto lleva acabo a instalar dependencias. La subida lo hago con [Beyond-Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/) para ir subiendo archivo por archivo.

Para empezar, lo que quiero subir es [dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf), los pasos que segui fueron:

1. Subir las dependencias del `dompdf` que estan en el `vendor`
2. Configurar la `config/app.php` segun documentacion
3. Actualizar los cambios del `composer.json - composer.lock` con el archivo local

Esos son los pasos que segui para subir la dependencia al hosting pero al final me salio el siguiente error:

> Class 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider' not found

Como dije antes, segui los pasos de la documentacion y subir los archivos necesarios pero aun asi sale eso, buscando informacion vi algunas posibles soluciones que se aplican utilizando **consola** pero yo no tengo acceso a ello.

Posibles soluciones: Limpiar el cache (Nose como hacerlo), reinstalar el dompdf, correr el `php artisan`, etc

Nose si los pasos que segui fueron los correctos para instalar una dependencia, espero puedan ayudarme gracias

Comment: @BetaM sobre la consola, no tengo acceso, sobre los errores, como dije, solamente subi las dependencias del vendor, configure el config/app.php, el composer.json y nada mas de ahi me sale errores que lo pondre en otra pregunta, pero aca es como el titulo, Instalar una dependencia en hosting correctamente

Comment: Esta bien lo que hice? o falta algo mas? Me refiero los pasos que segui para instalar la dependencia en el hosting

Comment: @BetaM Ok editare mi pregunta segun eso, gracias

Comment: @BetaM listo, ya lo modifique

Comment: prueba subir también el archivo `/vendor/autoload.php` además de las dependencias del dompdf que estan en el vendor